# Cursor moving too far from the last letter in typing animation

Tags: html, css, web

I'm trying to have a typing animation in my home page, something similar to [this](https://codepen.io/crazeddd/pen/KKGeZYo).

When I check out the result on my own website (currently on localhost), the cursor moves too far away from the last letter, even thought I actually want it to be rendered and blinked right after the sentence has finished. I've been playing around with the values I've given in my code, and the result is mostly the same. Weird thing is that it only happens the first time I check it on localhost, and if I refresh the page it works properly from then on. I really don't know what I'm doing wrong, so I'd appreciate any hints or help.

Thank you in advance!

Here's my code:

**code.html**

```
<body>
<div id="intro">
<div class="txt">a passionate programmer</div>
</div>
</body>
```

**code.css**

```
.txt{
    background: none;
    font-family: 'VT323', monospace;    
    width: 23ch;
    animation: type 2.5s steps(26), blink .5s step-end infinite alternate;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-right: 5px solid;
    color: #FAEFE8;
    /*font-family: Inconsolata;*/
   text-shadow: 0 0 30px #EE8742; 
    font-size: 55px;
    place-items: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  
  @keyframes type{
    from{width: 0%}
  }
  
  @keyframes blink{
    50%{border-color: transparent}
  }
```

Expected output:
[image]

The output I currently get (which is not desired):
[image]

Comment: If I specify a font I know to be monospace (Courier) then the blinking cursor ends up in the right place.

Comment: @AHaworth Wow, it works for me too if the font is monospace, this is really... weird XD So basically I can't have my preferred font if I want to have the typing animation, or is there a way around this?

Comment: Well, you can’t use this method with a variable font because your method depends on knowing that each character has the same width, the final width you have set being 23ch. Typewriters have fixed width characters…